# Disable Cloud logging GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

why i cannot disable the cloud logging

i tried using console and command but still not working

```
    gcloud beta resource-manager org-policies enable-enforce \
  constraints/gcp.disableCloudLogging --project x4-stag
```

and got this error

```
C:\Users\aji> gcloud beta resource-manager org-policies enable-enforce constraints/gcp.disableCloudLogging --project x4-stag
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.resource-manager.org-policies.enable-enforce) User [aji.fa@xxx.com] does not have permission to access project [x4-stag:setOrgPolicy] (or it may not exist): The caller does not have permission
```

for IAM role is using owner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your identity is lacking permission to enforce a policy. Add the IAM role **Organization Policy Administrator** (roles/orgpolicy.policyAdmin) at the Organization level. This role cannot be granted at the Folder or Project level.

[Organization Policy roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#organization-policy-roles)

Comment: ok it work thank you